# Rewrite rule not working in child theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am using this rewrite rule function but it does not work in child theme. It seems not going inside callback function at all.

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $term_obj = get_queried_object();
    //print_r($term_obj);
    if(isset($term_obj->term_id) && $term_obj->term_id!=""){
        $aNewRules = array('casselberry-antique-white/([^/]+)/?$' => 'templates/product-list-template.php?manufacturer_id=$matches[1]');
        $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
        return $aRules;
  }
  else{
    return $aRules;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of isset try using property_exists

see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

When you call add_rewrite_rules function?

You need init hook, add_rewrite_rule is a function core WordPress [see link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)

```php
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'casselberry-antique-white/([^/]+)/?$',
        'templates/product-list-template.php?manufacturer_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});
```